# How to transfer or get values from 1 user control to/from other user control.cs

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to transfer values from here

```
public partial class Burger : UserControl
{
    public int t_num_Z_bur = 0;
    public int t_num_B_bur = 0;
    mol md = new mol();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t_num_Z_bur++;
        md.my(180);
        md.sou = "180";
        textBox1.Text = t_num_Z_bur.ToString();
    }

}
```

And this the user control from here I get the values and make changes in textbox 1. How it could change the values?

```
public partial class mol : UserControl
{
    public string sou
    {
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    public void my (int value)
    {
        textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Little unclear, *i get the values and make changes in textbox 1. How it could change the values* which value you want to update as per changes in textBox1

Comment: So when button is clicked in Burger you want value to be updated in textbox which is in mol?

Comment: Question is not clear and user is not giving clarification, still the post having 2 upvotes, please use your privilege properly

Comment: If you understand flow properly, Same logic of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224947/trouble-passing-new-object-back-to-main-form-c-sharp-net/50225360#50225360) may apply here too

Comment: i want to make a changes in textBox1 in the user control named mol.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with communication between containers is to implement an observer class

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. 
(Wikipedia)

the way i do this is creating an Observer class, and inside it write something like this:

```
1    public delegate void dlFuncToBeImplemented(string signal);
2    public static event dlFuncToBeImplemented OnFuncToBeImplemented;
3    public static void FuncToBeImplemented(string signal)
4    {
5         OnFuncToBeImplemented(signal);
6    }
```

so basically: the first line says that there would be a function that somebody else will implement

the second line is creating an event that occurs when the delegated function will call

and the third line is the creation of the function that calls the event

so in your UserControl, you should add a function like this:

```
private void ObserverRegister()//will contain all observer function registration
{
    Observer.OnFuncToBeImplemented += Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented;
    /*and more observer function registration............*/
}


void Observer_OnFuncToBeImplemented(string signal)//the function that will occur when  FuncToBeImplemented(signal) will call 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Signal "+signal+" received!", "Atention!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

and in your Form you should do something like:

```
public static int signal = 0;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Observer.FuncToBeImplemented(signal);//will call the event in the user control
}
```

and now, you can register this function to a whole bunch of other controls and containers and they will all get the signal

I hope this would help :)